# "The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine" Win 10 64 bit

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, ms-access

Pardon my asking this again, but most of these post are very old.
Anyways, I am running **Windows 10 on a 64 bit machine. Using VB and VS2015, I am sourcing data from a MS Access 2019  accdb database.**
Due to reading many posts here, I have downloaded the 2010 Access Database engine, but STILL get the "The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine"
I can only connect to my DB through a DotNet 2 connection which doesn't seem stable, not to mention out of date.
Any ideas?

Comment: Did you install the 64 bit version? Do you have Office installed? If yes is the 32 or 64 bit version? Then why 2010? There is the 2016 version.

Comment: Seems you have a different building “CPU destination” of your software (if it still work on .NET 2.0). I think you have x86 for .NET 2.0 and AnyCPU on current project.  Isn’t it?

Comment: If you have left `Prefer 32-bit` checked for a reason, then you need the 32 bit Provider, otherwise, install the 64 bit Provider, if not already installed. Note that you can install the 32 bit version of the 2010 release and the 64 bit version of the 2016 release (or the other way around), but not the 32 and 64 bit versions of the same release. If you use the `AnyCPU` profile without `Prefer 32-bit`, you can use both the 32 and 64 bit versions.

Comment: try install Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC) to you machine

Comment: What version of the data engine did you install, the x64 bit verison, or the x32 bit version? If you installed x64 bit version, then you MUST set/force your proejct to run as x64 bits. And WHEN you do this, the connection builders can be used (oleDB), but the test connection for x64 bits will ALWAYS fail (since VS is a x32 bit application). While the test connection buttion will fail, it will work WHEN you run the code. However, if you using office x32, then of course download + install x86 (x32) bit version of ACE.

Comment: @Albert D. Kallal You don't need to *force* the app to build as x64t if you use the 64 bit version of the driver. AnyCPU will do. The bitness of Visual Studio is not relevant. It *may* become relevant if you use the VS tools to build your stuff, but it's not relevant per se.

Comment: READ again! I stated that if you using the x64 bit version of ACE you MUST set the project to x64 bit CPU. If you do not, then VS will by default run the application when using ANY CPU as a x32 bit in-line process. You MUST set the project to run as x64 bits if you using x64 ACE. I also stated that since VS is a x32 bit program, you CAN USE the connection builder, but WHEN you hit test connection, it will fail, since again VS is a x32 bit program, but when running and forced as x64 bits, the code will work and run.  So yes, since ACE is un-managed code you MUST force project to x64

Comment: You can't mix and match and run unmanaged code as x32 bits if that code library and external code is x64 bits. Un-managed code does not have the ability to run "in-process" as different CPU then what the un-managed code was written as. For managed code, it don't matter since CLR code can run as x32 or x64 bits. This is NOT the case WHEN using un-managed code libraries of which ACE is. As a result, you have to force/set the project (any CPU, or x86 will not work - ONLY force of project to x64 bits will work. Since VS is x32 then also the connection builders work but test connection does not.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal *I stated that if you using the x64 bit version of ACE you MUST set the project to x64*: no, you don't. That's quite easy to test, so there's no much else to add. -- Make a new Project, remove `Prefer 32-bit`, pick the `AnyCPU` profile, make sure only the 64bit version of one of the Providers is installed. Open a connection and read the data from a MS Access db. -- Install the 32bit of the other provider, same Project configuration, now open a connection using this other Provider. -- Note that I don't use the VS tools for any kind of data access procedure (except Azure).

Comment: Sorry - it does not work that way. We talking about ACE, not JET. JET is ONLY available as x32 (and is limited to mdb files).  The oleDB .net providers work as x32 or x64, HOWEVER the ACE data engine does NOT. You confusing providers (oleDB) as opposed to the data engine library.  You can connect to SQL server with a x32 bit or x64 bit provider (it is a provider, and a socket connection). But ACE is a un-managed library. You obviously don't grasp the difference here.  Been doing this for 10 years - you HAVE to run the project as x64 bits. Try it against a accDB file - you see what occures.

Comment: But yes  - go ahead and test this - you report back and you find 100% exact behaviors I outlined.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal I'm not confusing anything and, yes, this has been tested a gazillion times (probably in the proper way): you **don't need** to build your application as x64 to use the 64 bit version of the driver. Make your test, as described (without any *interference* from Visual Studio), you'll see.

Comment: You most certainly do if you don't launch the application as in-process x64 bits. You can use ANY CPU - but if you launch that app as x32, then it will fail. In fact, try the reverse - launch that app as x64 bits and try to use x32 ACE - it will also fail. Bottom line: if you leave CPU setting to ANY, then your code will fail if it gets launched as x32 bits for ace x64. And the failure will also occur if you do the reverse. (launched as x32 bits and you try to use x64 bits. Again, from the dwan of computers - you can't mix in-process bit size of un-managed code parts - it does not work.

Comment: What you describe ONLY works due to launching a ANY CPU .exe from the x64 bit  command line - so yes, of course that works. But try launching that app from a x32 bit command session - the code will fail. So yes, if you exit VS and do this outside of VS? Then you ONLY BY LUCK having this work because you using a x64 bit command line to launch the application. Try reverse - use any CPU - and try to work with a x32 bit version of Access (ACE) - the code will not work. Again: have to match the bit size. Your example is matching bit size due to using x64 bit command line to launch the ANY  CPU app.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal When you start an application using the `AnyCPU` profile in a 64bit OS (as the OP is doing), the app starts as a 64bit Process. You can verify this in TaskManager. Then, having installed the the 32Bit version of one Provider and the 64bit version of the other (you cannot have both in the same bitness anyway), create two connections: one using  `"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=SomeName.accdb;Persist Security Info=false;"`, the other `"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0;Data Source=SomeName.accdb;Persist Security Info=false;"`.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal Have, e.g., two Buttons that load data using the two different Providers. Now, start you app either running it in Visual Studio or starting the .exe in Explorer. The result is that you can use both Providers, in two different Bitness, from the same 64bit Process. -- I've seen this kind of thing mentioned elsewhere, in relation to the Process Bitness and Visual Studio; for example, some people think that you cannot use a 64bit UserControl in Visual Studio because the IDE (?) is 32bit. Of course is not true. You can. The UC needs to be create in a Library that targets `AnyCPU`.

Comment: No, you simply cannot do as you are suggesting. You cannot use a x32 bit provider if your app is running in-process as x64 bits. And the reverse is also true.  and what do you mean from the same x64 bit process? Either that process is running as x64 bits, or it is NOT - it can't and does not run as both.  If you use ANY cpu, then the .net process can and will launch as EITHER a x64 or x32 (from VS, it will always be x32). From command prompt - it will depend. You can't have the in-process x64 .net application use a x32 bit ACE data engine. and the reverse is also true. And which two providers?

Comment: Take a look at my additional screen shots in my answer below - I just edited it - I show how to choose ACE, or JET.

Comment: Yes, you can do it. It's tested over and over. Please, just test it yourself, would you? It's very simple, it just takes 5 minutes. Last comment, no need to reply.

Comment: I alrady have - I have a sample download in my answer below - try the x32 one, and try the x64 one - tell me which one works - and which one does not. If both work, then you have both a x32 bit version of ACE installed and a x64 bit one. But the bit size of the .net project MUST MATCH the bit size of ACE - they can't be miss-matched. Try my sample download linked in my post below.

Comment: Just as a follow up in regards to the UC? yes, that can work because you using managed code and the UC is set to any cpu. But JET/ACE is NOT managed code - so you can't do as you suggest.  As I stated, I provided a link with a download with 2 versions. Remember, if you connecting to JET/ACE, then also REMEMBER TO display in code during testing what bit size you are using.  So, any cpu and a external assembly? Sure, either bit size can consume that any CPU .net assembly. What you can't do is consume un-managed windows x32 code (JET/ACE x32), or in this case windows x64 bit code - (ACE x64).

Comment: it is possbile to build a inter-op bridge - but as a normal course of action? No, you can't run x64 bit ACE data engine with a in-process x32 .net program - and the reverse is also true. You can try my link in the post below - you see that either x32 or the x64 bit program works - but not both.  There is no inter-op bridge (marshaling) that been built for JET/ACE, and thus you limited to the rules I outlined in the posts in this thread.

Answer (score 5):

You don't mention what verison of ACE you installed.

If your office is x32, then I suggest that you download + use the x86 (x32) bit verison of ACE.

However, if office is going to be x64 bits, then you MUST download and use the x64 bit version of ACE. You ALSO then must force your project to x64 bits. ANY CPU, or x86 settings for your project will NOT work, since when you using un-managed code (which ACE is), then you MUST force the project to the ocrrect bit size.

You also notice that you can use the VS built in connection builders, but keep in mind that WHEN using the x64 bit version of ACE, then you CAN use the connection builders, but since VS is a x32 bit program, then the TEST connection button will ALWAYS fail, but WHEN you run the code (and forced as x64), then the connections will work. So caution here, since when using x64 ACE, the test connection buttons in VS will fail, but such code will connect and work when you run the project. If you using x32 ACE, then ANY CPU can be used, but you risking problems, since ANY CPU during development results in a x32 bit "in-process" since VS is a x32 bit program. However, if you launch a .exe ANY CPU program from the windows x64 bit shell, then you going to get a x64 bit "in line" process, and once again x32 ACE will fail as a result. (but if you launch the .exe from a x32 bit version of the windows shell, the you DO  get a x32 bit process, and ACE x32 can be used).

As a result of above?
Then do NOT use ANY CPU - since your resulting program and process can well be launched as x32, or x64 - and you often be rolling dice here. So, if using x32 (x86) ACE, then force the project to x86.

And the same goes if you planning to use x64 ACE, then FORCE the project settings to x64 bits.

As a FYI:
Since VS is a x32 bit program, then you can use the connection builders (say in settings), and build a oleDB connection to ACE. However WHEN using x64 bit ACE, the "test connection" button will ALWAYS fail. You have to actually run the program (forced as x64) to see the connection work - the test connection button can't work since VS is x32 bits, and when ACE is x64, then the test connection button will give a FALSE ERROR that you can't connect (you have to as noted run the project - forced as x64 bits).

So the first question and issue?

Which version of ACE did you install? (x32 bits (x86), or (x64 bits (x64)).

So there are two versions of ACE you can download and install - you want to choose the correct version for your project settings, and you ALSO must set the project settings You do NOT want to use ANY CPU, but actually choose and force the project to be and run as the correct bit size.

While .net code and assemblies can run as either CPU settings, ACE is a external library, and is un-managed code. As a result such external code libraries are pre-compiled as x32, or as x64 bits. As a result, your project settings MUST match the given version (bit size) of ACE  you plan to run.

Edit:

So in summary:

YOu have to install the ACE data engine. It can be found here:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920

In above, when you hit download, you THEN are given a chance to select the correct bit size of the ACE database engine.

You HAVE to select the bit size you want to use.

That is this one:
[image]

Now again (repeated for the 100th time).

You CAN use the connection builder in VS, but WHEN using x64, then the Test connection button WILL AWAYS fail (it fails because VS is a x32 bit application - it can't ever connect to x64 ACE).

So builder DOES work, but TEST connect does NOT!!!

So, when using the connection builder, you see this:

[image]

Select "change" in above, and then you get this:

[image]

Ok, and then this:

[image]

You NEED to CHECK the advanced tab, since this lets you choose between JET and ACE.

And for x64 bits you can ONLY choose/use ACE, and you MUST choose ACE, as there is no x64 bit version of JET.

So you see this choice in advanced:

[image]

So in above, you MUST choose ACE and NOT JET.

Ok, now with above, then we have this:

[image]

So, you can hit OK, you can use browse. And you CAN AND SHOULD check on advanced to be 100% sure that you selected ACE in palce of jet.

BUT YOU CAN NOT USE TEST CONNECTION for x64 - it DOES NOT WORK, NEVER DID, and since Visual Studio is a x32 bit program, then it CAN NOT EVER EVER EVER PASS THE TEST CONNECTION option (so don't use it!!!).

Now of course, you ALSO MUST set the project to x64 bits, like this:

[image]

If you don't see nor have a x64 option, then choose configuration manager, and create + choose and setup a x64 bit configuration for the project.

Also, I have a .net test program. You can find this download here:

In above, I have a x32 bit verison, and a x64 bit version. you can try running EITHER one, and see which one works - try the x32 bit one, and then try the x64 bit one. You find out VERY quick and easy as to which bit size of ACE you have installed and setup on your computer.

https://1drv.ms/u/s!Avrwal_LV4qxhpdBOVIuD9P4iJmZhg?e=cFs8LY

In above, you find two .exe files. One .net example compiled to x32, and the other compiled as x64.

[image]

When you run the x32 one you get this:

[image]

So the above SHOWS the bit size of the .net applcation.

And you can thus try the x32 one, or the x64 one and SEE which of the two connects.

Comment: My Office is 64 and all boxes in my VS database properties point to a .Net Framework 4. When creating a new database connection, i have no other choices but"Microsoft Access Database File (OLE DB)".  Hitting Ok or Test connection throws the ace 12. error. I cannot get past this box. Browsing my installed programs does not show  ANY ace entries. Planning which to run,? I was working pretty good with MS Access *.mdb but it was suggested to use the accdb version, which I cant make the connection.

Comment: As noted, you can use the connection builder with x64, but you CAN NOT use the TEST connection button - even WHEN setup correctly, the TEST connection button will ALWAYS fail. However, if you set the project to x64 bits (as opposed to ANY CPU), then you can of course hit f5 to run the project, and if ACE x64 is installed correctly, then the project will run. So for x64 ACE the test connection button will ALWAYS fail, but running the code (even in debug) will and should work. For x32 ACE, then test connection will always work, but test connection for x64 never works - running project should

Comment: See my edit - I show in screen shots HOW to select ACE in place of JET.

Comment: Thanks Albert.  Although my head is spinning with all the info, i do know that in the select database window, i can neither select test, as you noted OR ok. Both throw the 12. not registered. Having said this, I am going to retreat a bit and try to give myself a fresh start. Thank you for your help and stay safe.

Comment: No problem - do try that link with the ACE install. and as noted, try the x64 bit download and install. And also as noted force your project to x64. These two steps should get you up and running. Also, as a SUPER quick test, you can try the linked download. There is nothing to install - just un-zip, and try running the two included tiny .exe files. One is for x32, and one is for x64. Try either one - if one of them works, then so will your project. It takes all of two minutes to try/test if ACE is working with that sample download.

Comment: Your AccessLooker ID 64/Ace which  worked and after making a data connection, and binding a single textbox, the following data was attached to a "jet4.0 provider is not registered" error. I have screen shots but dont know how to attach them here.

Comment: You can't use JET in x64 bits - there is no x64 bit version of JET ever made. If using x64 bits, then JET is 100% NOT an choice and is off the table. However, ACE can open most mdb files (2000-2003). I don't think it can open access 97 mdb files. You could try downloading the ACE 2010 version (x64), as that version still can open a mdb file. However, if you using a accDB file - then you must use ACE. But for mdb and x64 bits? Your options are limited - you must use ACE, and will have to try a older version if you looking to open older mdb files - best to use accDB files, but ACE can open them.

Comment: Correction:"ou could try downloading the ACE 2010 version (x64), as that version still can open a mdb file. " What I mean is ACE can open mdb files - but not really older versions - but the ACE 2010 engine will have MUCH better luck opening older mdb files. If possible, i would stick to using accDB files for x64 bit operations. But, ACE can open mdb files - just not really older ones.

Comment: my mdb files are this year. i cannot successfully close a setup window using an accdb. I can setup a mdb but i always get a conflict error ; in Public Overloads Overridable Function Fill(ByVal dataTable As HealthDataSet.tTemperatureDataTable) As Integer
            Me.Adapter.SelectCommand = Me.CommandCollection(0)
            If (Me.ClearBeforeFill = true) Then
                dataTable.Clear
            End If
            Dim returnValue As Integer = Me.Adapter.Fill(dataTable) connected to the (dataTable)

Comment: Ok, different issues. The key issue here is that you can now use x64, and open a mdb, or a accDB file with x64 ACE. I would suggest starting  new question now that you are able to open a mdb with x64 Ace. Other issues such as opening and using oleDB provider, and using a dispose to close down (even when inside of a using block) is a very different issue(s) to deal we. This post is about resolving the x64 bit version issue, and that you can or cannot open a mdb file with x64 ACE That goal is achieved - so additonal issues need to be a new question.

Comment: Thank You Albert. I REALLY appreciate the time your spent on my issue. REALLY!